# Get fields to appear in fields list, arguments list and filters list in view

Tags: 6

I am using hook_form_alter and adding a extra form field to drupal node form. All works fine, but in view this field is not show up. How do i add this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding form element using hook_form_alter use CCK field. View will not understand your custom field but a CCK fields are integrated in views.

EDIT

Please check for [Tag User](http://drupal.org/project/taguser) module.

Comment: But i am adding a user autocomplete or say tagging thing while adding a node. this is totally customized. So i need to add it using alter functions.

Answer (score 0):

To make you understand the difference between a **form field** and a **CCK field** in a Node form relationship:

### **Formfield**

You could add a formfield to a node form, but this would only add a `<input>` field to your form. After adding this field, you could use Drupal's Form API ([Drupal.org Form API quickstart guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826)) to for example validate the fields, or process them in any way you see fit. To be clear, without any validation, post-processing, etc. your field will **not** be used in any way.

That being said, a form field is only interesting when you make a custom module, which needs some additional information about a node which will be created / editted.

### **CCK field** (Simply: **Fields** in Drupal 7)

You have numerous types of fields (eg. Text, number, references, file, etc...) which you can assign to different node types. For example, you could add a [**imagefield**](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) field to a node-type "Employee" to make it possible to add a picture of a employee.

I hope this clears it up a bit for you.

**edit**

I noticed you where trying to add a "user autocomplete" field? Try out the [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) User reference field, it's in the base module if you're using Drupal 6. If you're using Drupal 7 you'll need a separate module: [References](http://drupal.org/project/references).

Comment: He needs solution for D6

Comment: I gave both, **CCK** for D6, **Fields** for D7